# Angular2: How to access DOM-Element (inside Component) from index.html with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, angular, typescript

I am trying to implement the great [PhotoSwipe-gallery](http://photoswipe.com/) (JavaScript) into my very first **Angular2-Project** (Typescript), and this one really gives me headache.

So PhotoSwipe is written in JavaScript. By it's instantiation it **accesses a specific DOM-element tagged by the classname 'my-gallery'** and parses all child-elements which obviously contain the image-data.

Here is a very simple version of what I am trying to achieve:

**index.html**

```
<body> 
  <my-app>
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      <my-images>
        <div class="my-gallery">
            <-- images -->
        </div>
      </my-images>  
  <my-app>
  <script>
    <--Want Access to class 'gallery' -->
    myGallery = document.querySelectorAll('my-gallery');
  </script>
<body>
```

In the above version **myGallery** is an empty object, so I wonder if this it is possible to gain access to elements from index.html, that are inside of other components in Angular2.

Another reason could be, that I actually get my images by an http.get-request, so maybe the script runs, before 'my-gallery' was loaded, but attempts to load other elements from index.html have also failed.

This is a very simplified version. In reality I am running a script that instantiates the PhotoSwipe-object. 
Of course I have tried to run the script from inside the component directly, apperently you can't run JavaScript-files inside a components-template.

Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Your script is executed before template loading. Why you don't create appropriate component for that? And so you can invoke script inside `ngAfterViewInit` hook.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your content to be inside the element tags you need to insert a `ng-content` element in your templates.

index.html

```html
<body> 
  <my-app>
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      <my-images>
        <div ref-myGallery class="my-gallery">
            <-- images -->
        </div>
      </my-images>  
  <my-app>
  <script>
    <--Want Access to class 'gallery' -->
    myGallery = document.querySelectorAll('my-gallery');
  </script>
<body>
```

my-image.component.ts

```js
import { Component, ContentChild, ElementRef, AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-images',
    template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`,
})
export class MyImageComponent implements AfterContentInit  {
    @ContentChild('myGallery', { read: ElementRef }) myGalleryEl: ElementRef;

    ngAfterContentInit() {
        var myGallery = this.myGalleryEl.nativeElement;
    }
}
```